# How to match username and password after querying

Tags: java, sql, authentication

How could I check if the username and password (taken as input in a login page) match? All of the information is stored in a Derby DB. I just need to know if the correct password is entered for a username that is given.

Here is my code:

```
public void checkIdPw(String userName, String passWord) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String checkPwforIdSQL = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM " + studentsTable + " WHERE USERNAME = '" + userName + "'";
        stmt.executeQuery(checkPwforIdSQL);
        stmt.close();
    } catch(SQLException sqlExcept) {
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: Please use PreparedStatement to construct your sql to prevent sql injection.

Comment: You can simply compare the password from database. But you should have hash the password for security purpose.

Comment: Where's the result set?

Comment: 1. where do you compare entered and stored password? 2. is your password stored as plain text or encrpyted?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I am actually just doing a very basic course registration system for practice. I am trying to understand this first and then maybe I'll worry about security later.

Comment: @Drogba How can I "simply" compare the two?

Comment: @Sudhanshu You are right... I need a result set. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoForberg I want to compare the entered and the stored password right after the user clicks the login button on the login page. This `checkIdPw()` method should be implemented in my `doCheck()` method in my Servlet class. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is poor security to store passwords unencrypted and encrypting them with something like [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) would be much better.

Something like the following should work for what you need.  Using a `PreparedStatement` is crucial and simple string concatenation should never be done as it allows for SQL injection attacks.

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT USERNAME FROM studentsTable WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?");
stmt.setString(1, username);
stmt.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // valid credentials
} else {
    // invalid credentials
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Depending on the nature of the site another good practice is to display the same generic message to the user on failed regardless of whether it was the username (or email address) or password that was incorrect. An example message is "Invalid username or password."  The benefit to this is that it helps prevent username harvesting as the attacker would not be able to tell from the error message that the username is valid.  For some sites this matters more than others and a site where the usernames are already public would not benefit as much as other harvesting methods are available.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I am actually just practicing to get a better understanding before I worry about security. My question is... Would this work: `if(rs.next()&&rs.getString(1)==passWord)`?

Comment: @Dinky you should not compare String using ==, use equals. And for this case, you don't need any comparison since a non-empty result means password matched.

Comment: @Dinky I saw your comment above about this just being for practice but password security is often overlooked so it was worth repeating. To do the comparison you mention you'd need to return PASSWORD from the query instead of USERNAME, remove the password comparison from the query, and update the if statement. I'd favor doing it as I noted above though.

Comment: Oh yeah... Should have used the `equals()` method for strings... Thanks!